# How to define (or print) a string with a loop on one line

Tags: python

As a challenge in 'efficiency' (rather, compactness of code, and certainly not pythonicness of code) I've been tasked to write code on a single line that will return a valid formula for the sequence, given the input will be a valid integer sequence separated by ", ". This is what I have:

```
for b in input(">>> ").split(", "): print("(((((",b,"-n)/(",b,"-n))+1)%2)*",b,")+",sep="",end="")
```

However, there are problems with this. The only real problem I'm concerned with is how to NOT print a "+" at the final item of the list (as it won't be added to anything). I was hoping there'd be a way with list comprehension but I can't think of one. Is this possible? If so, can I even add in error handling, that ignores items of the input list that aren't valid integers? (By the way, the maths works out. I think.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use join to contact item together

```
 "+".join( "((((({}-n)/({}-n))+1)%2)*{})".format(*([item]*3)) for item in  input(">>> ").split(", ") )
```

example:

```
"+".join( "((((({}-n)/({}-n))+1)%2)*{})".format(*([item]*3)) for item in [1,2,3,4] )
'(((((1-n)/(1-n))+1)%2)*1)+(((((2-n)/(2-n))+1)%2)*2)+(((((3-n)/(3-n))+1)%2)*3)+(((((4-n)/(4-n))+1)%2)*4)'
```